# Using exception-mapping locally and globally with same exception - which one will have high priority

Tags: java, struts2

I have local exception-mapping for action level and global-exception-mapping in which exception is of same type - then which one will be having high priority whether global one is executed or local one?

```
<action name="User_save" class="">
    <exception-mapping exception="java.sql.SQLException"
            result="error"/>
    <result name="error">/jsp/Error.jsp</result>
    <result>/jsp/Thanks.jsp</result>
</action>

<global-results>
    <result name="error">/jsp/Error.jsp</result>
    <result name="sqlError">/jsp/SQLError.jsp</result>
</global-results>
<global-exception-mappings>
    <exception-mapping exception="java.sql.SQLException"
            result="error"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

When declaring an exception mapping, the Interceptor will find the closest class inheritance match between the Exception thrown and the Exception declared. The Interceptor will examine all declared mappings applicable to the action mapping, first local and then global mappings. If a match is found, the Result is processed, just as if it had been returned by the Action.

This process follows the same rules as a Result returned from an Action. It first looks for the Result in the local action mapping, and if not found, it looks for a global Result.

Answer (score 0):

Throw a SQLException from your action, and you'll have your answer.

Or read [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.3/docs/exception-configuration.html), which says:

> The Interceptor will examine all declared mappings applicable to the
>   action mapping, first local and then global mappings